# Cesiumjs: How to iterate data from GeoJsonDataSource

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

could anyone tell me how to get the position data from GeoJsonDataSource? Here is what I am doing:

```
entity1 = Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource.fromUrl('../../SampleData/markersdata.geojson');
var array1 = entity1.entities.entities;        //According to document, this should an array of entity instances, but it only returns an empty array.
console.log(array1);
// []
//If I do this:
var assocArray = entity1.entities._entities;       //This returns an associative array
var markersArr = assocArray.values;          //I expect this returns an array of values, but it still returns empty array.
console.log(markersArr);
// []
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Several questions that might be typo: l.2 `x`->`entity1`? l.3 `assocArray`->`array1`? l.6 `x`->`entity1`?

Comment: @dgiugg Thanks for replying. Sorry it was a typo in this question, x should be entity1. In my project on the server, when I check the members of entity1.entities in line 2, or assocArray in line 6, the re are 500 data instances in them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`GeoJsonDataSource.fromUrl` returns a new instance that is still in the process of loading data (the `isLoading` property will be true). You can't use the data in the data source until the `loadingEvent` event is fired.  In cases like this, it's easier to create the new instance yourself and use `loadUrl` instead.  This is still an asynchronous operation; but it returns a promise that resolved when the data is ready.  See Cesium's [GeoJSON Sandcastle demo](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=GeoJSON%20and%20TopoJSON.html&label=Showcases) for an example of doing this.  This is a common pattern, not just in Cesium, but JavaScript in general.  You can read more about the promise system used by Cesium [here](https://promisesaplus.com/).

Here's a small snippet of code that shows you how to iterate.

```
var dataSource = new Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource();
dataSource.loadUrl('../../SampleData/ne_10m_us_states.topojson').then(function() {
    var entities = dataSource.entities.entities;
    for (var i = 0; i < entities.length; i++) {
        var entity = entities[i];
        ...
    }
});
viewer.dataSources.add(dataSource);
```